# Receiving Access Denied with altered CRUD paths in ECK

Tags: 7, entities

I have altered the CRUD paths for entity types and bundles created with [Entity Construction Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck).  The change propogates correctly, all views which use the ECK provided views fields (Link, Edit, Delete) are now using the correct URL.

The issue is when trying to hit those URL's, the page is always access denied.  What I have found in my troubleshooting:

1. The menu is built within [eck.entity.inc](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/eck/tree/eck.entity.inc?h=7.x-2.x#n93).  I have used the following test code, inserted at line #93

   ```
   if ($bundle->name == 'inventory_item' && $action_label == 'Edit') {
     print_r($access_args);
     die();
   }
   // result = Array ( [0] => edit [1] => inventory_item [2] => inventory_item [3] => 5 )
   ```

   Note that the `$access_args` does contain the correct entity id (index 3 in the result array).
2. The menu `access callback` is `eck__entity_menu_access()` which is found in [`eck.module`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/eck/tree/eck.module?h=7.x-2.x#n761) and I have included the following there, inserted at line 762:

   ```
   if ($action == 'edit' && $bundle_name == 'inventory_item') {
     print_r(func_get_args());die();
   }
   // result = Array ( [0] => edit [1] => inventory_item [2] => inventory_item [3] => )
   ```

   Note that index 3 (`$entity_id`) is null now.

I can't figure out where the entity id is lost.  I don't think it matters, but I did check the loader, `eckentity_load()` and it is loading the correct entity.

Any ideas why the entity id is not making it to the access callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see an example of an original ECK path (for a single entity), and then your updated one. If you re-arranged the arguments, or changed their quantity, the `access arguments` passed to the access callback will not be correct.

You will almost certainly need to implement `hook_menu_alter` to update the `access arguments` property of ECK paths.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, you forced me to re-think my assumptions.  I was convinced I was getting what I needed because the $access_arguments[3] happened to be the entity id of the item I was testing -- everything I know about access arguments being a position in the path was lost :)

It might be prudent to add that one also needs to update the `page arguments` property.